# setOnClickListener on RelativeLayout with ImageButton and TextField

Tags: android, listener, android-relativelayout, imagebutton, onclicklistener

I have a RelativeLayout and with it I have an ImageButton and a TextField.

When I set the on click listener to this RelativeLayout it works fine if I touch the text, but the button does not trigger it.

If I add the on click listener to the ImageButton as well, it works.
Do I really need to do this? Or am I missing something? It seems like a waste to have to do both, especially when I have this situation A LOT in my app.

Thanks in advance

```
m_view.findViewById(R.id.menu_relativeLayout_home).setOnClickListener(this);
m_view.findViewById(R.id.menu_imageButton_home).setOnClickListener(this);

   @Override
   public void onClick(View p_view)
   {
      switch (p_view.getId()) 
      {
         case R.id.....:
         {
            ...
            break;
         }
         case R.id....:
         {
            ...
            break;
         }
         case R.id.menu_imageButton_home:
         case R.id.menu_relativeLayout_home:
         {
            GoHome();
            break;
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: try putting clickable false in xml for ImageButton

Comment: By setting android:duplicateParentState property to all children solved your problem??

Comment: Any one know the better solution for this instead of adding 2 listeners for Relative layout and ImageButton?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have to add the onClickListener to both. How else would the item have a registered listener then.

Comment: Hmm, but I never set it on the TextField but clicking on the text works. Or is it that I just happen to be touching through the text?

Answer (score 1):

Set `android:duplicateParentState="true"` to all children, this will propagate click to all children.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `android:duplicateParentState` to `true` this will solve your problem and set clickListner to parent only.